# Reading user attributes

Tags: truevault

So on create/update methods, there's a attributes param, described as "base64 encoded JSON document describing the user attributes".

However, on both the read user and the auth/me endpoints, it doesn't return the attributes. How can we retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'full=1' as a query parameter and it should return the User attributes for both endpoints. We missed that param in our docs so we will go ahead and make the addition.